# Rendering issue after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, redirect, browser

I'm using Bottle microframework (but I doubt my issue comes from it)

First if I define a simple redirect from /test_redirect to /x it works.  So Bottle redirect() on simple case works.

Now I have a page /buy that uses Stripe Checkout (custom form) pointing to my server /stripe_process
Basically Stripe Checkout verifies credit card transaction, creates a token and POST it to my /stripe_process.

/stripe_process does its stuff (calling Stripe to charge the card) then when transaction is success, i use instruct Bottle to:

```
redirect('/transaction_summary')
```

My webserver logs show that indeed /transaction_summary is called and server-side script is processed (I put flags in my script to check this), and its template is returned (browser 'Network' analysis gives a 303 then a 200 on /transaction_summary, I even get the correct response data: seems 100% normal), but on the browser page nothing happens (I still have my initial page /buy in url field, instead of having been redirected to /transaction_summary): *browser received the /transaction_summary response, a preview is visible on Chrome devtools preview mode, but is not displaying it!*

Also if in /stripe_process I change redirect() with a simple return template(), same issue: no data is processed by the browser.

Any clue ? This behaviour have been observed on 100% my tests:
- Firefox / Windows
- Chrome / iOS 9 (iPad)
- Chrome / linux
- Iceweasel / linux
- Chrome / Android
- Chrome / OSX

I suspect it has something to do with Stripe Checkout taking over something (since redirect() works perfectly in my simple test), but I can't figure the reason and how to solve this.

If from Chrome-devtools-network section I go to last action (ie /transaction_summary download) and open /transaction_summary in new tab, it renders perfectly.
*So it's not a bottle problem, nor webserver. I suspect more on Stripe checkout modal/popup behaviour*

$(window).on('popstate', function() { handler.close(); }); is present as stripe docs instruct but anyway stripe_handler is properly closed after token received (I checked with handler.closed callback...)

EDIT:
If I replace *redirect()* with straight *return template()*, same issue: html stuff is downloaded by the browser, avail on preview, but not rendered on main window.

EDIT2:
if I add on my page a href to /test_redirect redirecting to /x it works. 
Note that this manual redirect work after Stripe checkout. The only difference with Stripe sequence here is user interaction ('click' on href) but as my redirect is same domain, browsers shouldn't block redirect anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that AJAX call used to send Stripe token to /stripe_process was handling redirect response. That's why on network I had 200 answer from webserver but all html page data was going into the AJAX callback and rendered. Thanks to Thomas for raising my nose from this issue.

Solution is /stripe_process to return 1 in case of success (instead of server-side redireciton), then make the redirection from AJAX success callback.